# ColdFusion 8 + Jrun on Windows Server 2008 R2 - trouble restarting

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, coldfusion, jrun

We have a legacy application with mainly Coldfusion 8 code, on Jrun4 application server on IIS 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2 (have to keep this going until it can be replaced).  It crashes or becomes unresponsive occasionally and we've always brought it back by restarting CF or Jrun, recycling application pool, or as last resort rebooting the server (which is a VM).

This time however, none of this has worked.  It appears as running in CF admin and in Jrun admin. Jrun Jar launcher and Jrun Service controller instances appear in task list but at 0 CPU.  Other CF applications on this server are up.

Googling has turned up nothing quite on point.  There have been no changes in code, DB or configuration since it was last working.  I'm still looking thru logs and haven't seen anything helpful.  jrun.xml and default-web.xml do not appear corrupted.  How can we get this restarted?

Answer (score 0):

We did get to the login page and could not get past it, this suggested a database problem, we tried login in SQL editor with the application credentials and found a lock, and the DBA corrected this.  So, somewhat of a false alarm, thanks to anyone who read tho.